# How to bind variable in style for progress bar set width in lighting web component Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

How to bind variable in style  for progress bar set width in lighting web component Salesforce
how to do that in salesforce lighting component

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.